# PHP: SimpleXML Warning parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a problem when I try to read a XML document with the PHP function simplexml_load_file() This is the warnings i get!

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): URL:81: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <img src=elite.png><br> in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): URL:81: parser error : attributes construct error in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <img src=elite.png><br> in URL line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): URL:81: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag img >line 81 in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <img src=elite.png><br> in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): URL:82: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 81 and programbeskrivelse in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): er vurderet og rådgivet af de bedste affiliates i branchen.</programbeskrivelse in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): URL:91: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 80 and program in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): </program> in URL on line 15
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in URL on line 15
```

As you see, I think it is the `<img src=elite.png>` tag in the XML file which is the problem:

```
<program><programid>ID</programid>
<programnavn>NAME</programnavn>
<programurl>URL</programurl>
<programbeskrivelse>SOME TEXT
<br>
<img src=elite.png><br>
SOME MORE TEXT</programbeskrivelse>
<programbetingelser></programbetingelser>
<kategoriid>5</kategoriid>
<kategorinavn>Tøj, mode, livsstil o.l.</kategorinavn>
<feed>ja</feed>
<kliksats>0.00</kliksats>
<leadsats>0.00</leadsats>
<provision>10.00</provision>
<affiliatelink>N/A</affiliatelink>
</program>
```

But it is an external XML file, so I can't just make changes in the XML file. Is there any ways to ignore the tag, og get i out before using SimpleXML? Or is there any other way to do it?

NOTE: all my URLs are rewriten with URL

And I have tried to use stripslashes() on the path, but thats not the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution based on Chrashspeeders comments:

```
$remove = file_get_contents(stripslashes("URL"));

$remove = preg_replace("/<programbeskrivelse>[\d\D]*?<\/provision>/", "", $remove);

$remove = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"), array("&", "&amp;"), $remove);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($remove);
```

I do not know anything about the performance, but it works.

```
$remove = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"), array("&", "&amp;"), $remove);
```

is for the & character in the links.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the XML is malformed.  If you were to fix the error (adding quotes to the property value) then it would cause other issues while reading the value of the `<programbeskrivelse>` node.  SimpleXML will ignore the tags within the string, making the value `SOME TEXT`.  The value of that node should most likely be within CDATA.  You may be able to detect tags within strings and wrap the node value in CDATA, but that may be tricky.  Offhand I can't think of a quick solution.

Comment: The only values I am interested in, is 
<programid>
<programnavn>
<affiliatelink>
So I do not need the <programbeskrivelse> value

Comment: You could load the contents of the XML file with [file_get_contents()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and remove the nodes whose values you don't care about, then load the resulting XML string using [simplexml_load_string()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).  Just make sure you keep the root node (in this case, `<program>` and `</program>`).

Comment: Would that not be ineffective performance, when I have a XML file on more than 7000 lines?

Comment: That depends.  You may want to benchmark the difference between loading a 7000 line XML file into SimpleXML versus a 3 line file and then benchmark parsing a 7000 line XML file to remove lines you aren't using.  Remember that when you create a SimpleXML object it has to parse the XML file and that takes time so by removing those lines you may actually end up improving performance.